# What does the expression "If we're on the money" mean?

Tags: meaning, questions

What does the expression "If we're on the money" mean?

Comment: Did you hear or read this somewhere? If so, what was the context?

Answer (score 6):

The expression probably means "if we are right.". The phrase ***on the money*** means **exactly correct or accurate**, verifiable in a wide range of online and dead-tree dictionaries.

American Heritage attributes it to 1940s US usage in and around horse racing circles, where a horse finishing first, second or third was "*in the money"*, and a bet placed on such a horse was **on the money.**

Comment: I'd also suggest that it relates to any form of gambling. If you're on the money, you've picked the right number, cards, horse, boxer, etc...